# NSNotification (or similar) to detect changes in Bluetooth connectivity on iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, bluetooth, notifications

When my iOS app opens it shows a list of local bluetooth devices, and you click one. If bluetooth is off there's a system alert that asks you to turn it on (with a button to go to Settings and another to click OK); If you turn on settings, it doesn't scan again and you have to

How can you register a kind of notification that runs a method when Bluetooth is turned on?

I saw something about "BluetoothAvailabilityChangedNotification" but that doesn't seem to get called when Bluetooth is turned on/off.

Here's the code I tried:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
 addObserver:self
 selector:@selector(bluetoothAvailabilityChanged:)
 name:@"BluetoothAvailabilityChangedNotification"
 object:nil];
```

...

```
-(void) bluetoothAvailabilityChanged: (NSNotification*) notification {
NSLog(@"Bluetooth changed %@",notification.description);
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

for getting bluetooth status change indication, you can try use CoreBluetooth lib 
1. link CoreBluetooth.framework to your project 
2. `#import <CoreBluetooth/CoreBluetooth.h>` in your .h file
3. implement `CBCentralManagerDelegate`
4. init the manager with self as the delegate
`CBCentralManager *centralManager = [[CBCentralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self queue:nil];`
5. keep it as a property as long as you need the updates:
`self.centralManager = centralManager;`
6. implement this method:

```
- (void)centralManagerDidUpdateState:(CBCentralManager *)central
{
   if ([central state] == CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOff) {
       NSLog(@"Bluetooth off");
   }
   else if ([central state] == CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOn) {
       NSLog(@"Bluetooth on");
   }
}
```

now try to enable/disable the bluetooth and look at the console to get the logs

Answer (score 0):

Implement [CBCentralManagerDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/CBCentralManagerDelegate_Protocol/index.html) protocol. It the only way to monitor bluetooth,

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Try: `@"BluetoothConnectabilityChangedNotification"`

I inherited code that registers for these notifications:

```
BluetoothAvailabilityChangedNotification
BluetoothConnectabilityChangedNotification
BluetoothPowerChangedNotification
```

and the app gets called for each of them.

I don't know where the definitions come from.  The underlying implementation is posting these.